# Trying to read xattr values on multiple files

Tags: terminal, zsh, extended-attributes

In trying to read all the ***values*** of the extended attributes on a single file, if I do

```
xattr -l <filename> | while read ATTR; do
  xattr -p $ATTR <filename>
done
```

I get what I expect.  But if I try to do multiple files with

```
for FILE in *; do
  echo "=== $FILE ==="
  xattr -l $FILE | while read ATTR; do
    xattr -p $ATTR $FILE
  done
done
```

for some files I get only the filename (no xattr, I suppose);
for some files I get

```
=== 154128428159.JPEG ===
xattr: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '154128428159.JPEG'
xattr: 154128428159.JPEG: No such xattr: com.apple.macl: 
xattr: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '154128428159.JPEG'
Not enough arguments for option -p. Expected at least 2 but got 1
```

and for other files,

```
xattr: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'record-image_-7.jpg'
xattr: record-image_-7.jpg: No such xattr: com.apple.macl: 
xattr: [Errno 63] File name too long: 'record-image_-7.jpg'
```

I tried putting `unset ATTR` or `ATTR=""` in the outer loop, but got the same results.

This is with either zsh or bash on macOS 13.5.2

Comment: Try it with just `xattr $FILE`, without any options. With the `-l` option, it will include the attribute values, which may include multiple lines and even empty lines.

Comment: The _values_ are what I want, as I said in the question.  According to the man page, `-l` lists the _names_ of the attributes.  But it only allows one attribute at a time, hence looping on the names.

Comment: OK, the format of the man page confused me.  -l changes the format rather than listing the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The man page format confused me and when Gairfowl explained that -l gives the values, I tested it with no options but (oops) the file I tested it on had no attributes.

So actually, I do need a loop, but it’s

```
for ATTR in $(xattr "$FILE"); do
  xattr -pl $ATTR "$FILE"
done
```

Comment: As always, use double quotes around `$FILE` to ensure it works with filenames containing whitespace. In case you still go with the outer loop (`for file in *; do`) you could also use `if [ -f "$FILE" ]; then ... fi` to only look at files (and skip directories etc).